# How to get a COM port of device and change it in python

Tags: python, serial-port, microcontroller, uart, device-manager

I have a microcontroller and I'm using UART to connect between the controller and my PC.
I need to determine in the PC to which COM port the microcontroller is connected and change it by a list of open COM ports. I wanted to use OS moudle of Python for changing but in every guide I looked people are doing in the Device Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to list the COM ports

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

all_comports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

for comport in all_comports:
    print(comport.device, comport.name, comport.description, comport.interface)
```

You can also list other information about the device using the following [reference](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo)

Comment: This is for getting all the COM ports, what I am searching is a way to change the actual COM port my microcontroller is connected to